# Map app / website that has surface information?

Tags: maps

I live in an area in the UK where some bridleways and paths have a type of mud that makes it unrideable when it is wet - "claggy mud" that completely clogs the drivetrain and tyres. I would like to know if there is an app / website that would allow me to plot routes that were 'weatherproof'.

Comment: Komoot claims "(you can) view inch-by-inch surface and way type readings to ensure you always know what’s coming"  I've never used it so can't comment on this functionality.  A real user can do a better answer than this, hence comment.

Comment: Komoot uses OpenStreetMap data. In lots of areas with diligent mappers the data is really good and detailed, in other areas … not so much. In any case they usually only distinguish between paved/unpaved or cobblestones (see https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/?key=surface#values) and [track type](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:tracktype) from grade1 (best) to grade5 (worst).

Comment: thanks. I've just noticed on the https://osmaps.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ site, it distinguishes a "track" so can cross-reference that for bridleways.

Comment: In addition, if I export a GPX file from a route I plan in osmaps website e.g. https://osmaps.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/route/5285803/Weatherproofish-mtb-route I can import into Komoot and get all the surface information there.